# How to debug armel and armhf binaries on x86-64 Ubuntu simultaneously?

Tags: debugging, arm, qemu

I'm working on the challenges on [ROP Emporium](https://ropemporium.com/). For the ARMv5 version of the [callme](https://ropemporium.com/challenge/callme.html) challenge, we are given two binaries and two shared libraries: `callme_armv5` with `libcallme_armv5.so` and `callme_armv5-hf` with `libcallme_armv5-hf.so`. The first pair appears to be using the armel EABI, while the second pair is using the armhf EABI.

In [Appendix B](https://ropemporium.com/guide.html#Appendix%20B) of ROP Emporium's Beginner's Guide, they show how to set up an environment for cross-platform debugging for ARM like so:

```
$ sudo apt install qemu-user libc6-armel-cross gdb-multiarch
$ sudo mkdir /etc/qemu-binfmt
$ sudo ln -s /usr/arm-linux-gnueabi /etc/qemu-binfmt/arm
```

That works great for armel, but it doesn't work for armhf. So I found this [post](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/a/8917/43351), showing how to set up an environment for cross-platform debugging of armhf binaries.

```
$ sudo apt install qemu-user libc6-armhf-cross gdb-multiarch
$ sudo mkdir /etc/qemu-binfmt
$ sudo ln -s /usr/arm-linux-gnueabihf /etc/qemu-binfmt/arm
```

This works fine for armhf, but not for armel ...

```
$ qemu-arm ./callme_armv5-hf  # Okay
...
$ qemu-arm ./callme_armv5     # FAIL
./callme_armv5: error while loading shared libraries: libcallme_armv5.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

The problem is that both setups create the same symlink, but to different directories, so I can debug armel and armhf binaries individually, but each time I want to switch, I have to change the symlink. Is there some way to set up an environment so I can debug both binaries simultaneously?

In case it's relevant, I'm running Ubuntu 20.04 under WSL2.